# Putting a list in the same order as another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

There's a bunch of questions that are phrased similarly, but I was unable to find one that actually mapped to my intended semantics.

There are two lists, `A` and `B`, and I want to rearrange `B` so that it is in the same relative order as `A` - the maximum element of `B` is in the same position as the current position of the maximum element of `A`, and the same for the minimum element, and so on.

Note that `A` is not sorted, nor do I want it to be.

As an example, if the following were input:

```
a = [7, 14, 0, 9, 19, 9]
b = [45, 42, 0, 1, -1, 0]
```

I want the output to be `[0, 42, -1, 0, 45, 1]`.

Please note that the intended output is not `[0, 45, 1, 0, 42, -1]`, which is what it would be it you zipped the two and sorted by `A` and took the resulting elements of `B` (this is what all of the other questions I looked at wanted).

Here's my code:

```
def get_swaps(x):
    out = []

    if len(x) <= 1:
        return out

    y = x[:]
    n = -1

    while len(y) != 1:
        pos = y.index(max(y))
        y[pos] = y[-1]
        y.pop()
        out.append((pos, n))
        n -= 1

    return out

def apply_swaps_in_reverse(x, swaps):
    out = x[:]
    for swap in swaps[::-1]:
        orig, new = swap
        out[orig], out[new] = out[new], out[orig]
    return out

def reorder(a, b):
    return apply_swaps_in_reverse(sorted(b), get_swaps(a))
```

The approach is basically to construct a list of the swaps necessary to sort `A` via selection sort, sort `B`, and then apply those swaps in reverse. This works, but is pretty slow (and is fairly confusing, as well). Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Is `numpy` an option?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Sure. That'd be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [7, 14, 0, 9, 19, 9]
b = [45, 42, 0, 1, -1, 0]
print zip(*sorted(zip(sorted(b), sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))[0]
#or, for 3.x:
print(list(zip(*sorted(zip(sorted(b), sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1])), key=lambda x: x[1][0])))[0])
```

result:

```
(0, 42, -1, 0, 45, 1)
```

You sort `a`, using `enumerate` to keep track of each item's original index. You zip the result with `sorted(b)`, then re-sort the whole thing based on `a`'s original indices. Then you call `zip` once more to extract just `b`'s values.

Comment: Oh, of course. That's perfect. I never even thought about using `enumerate`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with `numpy` by sorting both lists (to get a mapping between the two lists) and by inverting one of the sorting permutations:

```
import numpy as np

a = [7, 14, 0, 9, 19, 9]
b = [45, 42, 0, 1, -1, 0]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)

ai = np.argsort(a)
bi = np.argsort(b)
aiinv = np.empty(ai.shape,dtype=int)
aiinv[ai] = np.arange(a.size)  # inverse of ai permutation

b_new = b[bi[aiinv]]
# array([ 0, 42, -1,  0, 45,  1])
```

[`numpy.argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) gives the indices (permutation) that will sort your array. This needs to be inverted to be used inside `b`, which can be done by the inverted assignment

```
aiinv[ai] = np.arange(a.size)
```