# How to sort a correlation matrix symmetrically?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, matrix, correlation

I'm dealing with correlation matrices and I want to rearrange the rows and columns so that the column with the highest average correlation is in the middle, the second best is one index above that, the third is one index below the middle, and so on and so forth.

In an example, this is the original matrix

```
[[ 1.        , -0.85240671,  0.93335528,  0.75431679,  0.81586527],
 [-0.85240671,  1.        , -0.874545  , -0.68551567, -0.8594703 ],
 [ 0.93335528, -0.874545  ,  1.        ,  0.7103762 ,  0.86104527],
 [ 0.75431679, -0.68551567,  0.7103762 ,  1.        ,  0.73345121],
 [ 0.81586527, -0.8594703 ,  0.86104527,  0.73345121,  1.        ]]
```

Ideally the new column/row order (using python indexing) is 3, 1, 2, 0, 4. So it would look like

```
[[1,-.686,.710,.754,.733], 
 [-.686,1,-.875,-.852,-.859], 
 [.710,-.875,1,.933,.861], 
 [.754,-.852,.754,1,.816], 
 [.733,-.859,.861,.816,1]]
```

None of the sorting algorithms I know seem to be able to deal with my goal of "symmetry". I'm using numpy for my matrices.

Some of the matrices will not have odd dimensions so I also want a way to deal with matrices with even numbers for their dimensions if possible. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the "determine the order of largest correlation" part of your question, but that's not really the core of the question.

I thought that, assuming your array is called `arr`, determining the order of descending correlation can be done by

```
corrs = arr.sum(axis=0)
corr_order = corrs.argsort()[::-1]
```

But the main part of your issue is filling up your matrix in this specific "largest in the middle" order. There has to be a more elegant way, but this is what I did to obtain the column order once you have your columns sorted decreasing:

```
ndim = arr.shape[0]
inds_orig = list(range(ndim))
inds = []
for _ in range(ndim):
    inds.append(inds_orig[(len(inds_orig)-1)//2])
    del inds_orig[(len(inds_orig)-1)//2]
inds = np.array(inds)
```

Now, the above for `ndim=5` will give us

```
array([2, 1, 3, 0, 4])
```

which seems to be exactly what you want: the first (largest) column in the middle, then each subsequent item on alternating sides.

Now we need to combine these two arrays to get a sorted+rearranged version of your original array. There's a slight inconvenience that using arrays to index your 2d array will trigger fancy indexing, when we really want to get basic indexing. So we need [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to convert our fancy indices into the equivalent effectively-slicing ones:

```
res = np.empty_like(arr)
res[np.ix_(inds,inds)] = arr[np.ix_(corr_order,corr_order)]
```

the result of which is

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.7103762 ,  0.75431679,  0.73345121, -0.68551567],
       [ 0.7103762 ,  1.        ,  0.93335528,  0.86104527, -0.874545  ],
       [ 0.75431679,  0.93335528,  1.        ,  0.81586527, -0.85240671],
       [ 0.73345121,  0.86104527,  0.81586527,  1.        , -0.8594703 ],
       [-0.68551567, -0.874545  , -0.85240671, -0.8594703 ,  1.        ]])
```

To check that this matrix is correct within my definition of "largest correlation":

```
>>> print(res.sum(axis=0))
[ 2.51262853  2.63023175  2.65113063  2.55089145 -2.27193768]
```

As you can see: largest in the middle, then one to the left, then one to the right, then the first, then the last.

Unless I'm mistaken, the other option would've been to [invert the sorting permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39755202/5067311) on the left-hand-side, and only index on the right-hand-side by indexing with one index array into the other. I'm not sure that would've been any clearer than this approach, so I stuck with this one.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes a lot of sense

Comment: @ij1994 please let me know if the above works for your application.