# Python: get the indices that would sort an array of strings to match another array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

my question is how to get the indices of an array of strings that would sort another array.

I have this two arrays of strings:

```
A = np.array([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ])
B = np.array([ 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c' ])
```

I would like to get the indices that would sort the second one in order to match the first. 
I have tried the np.argsort function giving the second array (transformed in a list) as order, but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be much apreciated.
Thanks and best regards,
Bradipo

> edit:
>
> ```
> def sortedIndxs(arr):
>     ???
> ```
>
> such that
>
> ```
> sortedIndxs([ 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c' ]) = [2,1,3,0]
> ```

Comment: Broader but applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755045/putting-a-list-in-the-same-order-as-another-list

Comment: Worth reading https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65031/creating-a-list-containing-the-rank-of-the-elements-in-the-original-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorised approach is possible via [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) together with [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
B = np.array(['d', 'b', 'a', 'c'])

xsorted = np.argsort(B)
res = xsorted[np.searchsorted(B[xsorted], A)]

print(res)

[2 1 3 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A code that obtains a conversion rule from an arbitrary permutation to an arbitrary permutation.

- creating indexTable: O (n)
- examining indexTable: O (n)
- Total: O (n)

---

```
A = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
B = [ 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c' ]

indexTable = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(B)}
// {'d': 0, 'b': 1, 'a': 2, 'c': 3}

result = [indexTable[k] for k in A]
// [2, 1, 3, 0]
```